# RegularExpression for checking string length?

Tags: javascript, regex

javascript regular expresion to check string length it will rise an error when string length exceeds 250 cheracters

Comment: Will it? Thanks for telling me. ...why are you using regex to check a string length, as opposed to `string.length`? Was there a question here, somewhere?

Comment: I think he was just dropping some knowledge on us from the future.

Comment: Next, he'll wanting a motorcycle and our clothes...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to match all characters and check only desirable length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548361/how-to-match-all-characters-and-check-only-desirable-length)

Answer (score 2):

there's no need to use an expensive regular expression

just use `length` property for strings, e.g.

```
var s = "abcd...xyz";
console.log(s.length)
```

and, just to answer the question, the regular expression would be

```
if (!(/^.{,250}/).test(s)) { /* error */ }
```

Comment: That re needs anchoring so it wont match 250 chars anywhere in a longer input I think; `/^.{0,250}$/`

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Match means error.

```
/.{251}/s
```