# How to match all characters and check only desirable length?

Tags: regex

I want to create a simple regex check to simply check the length of the text, nothing else. Closest I got was `[^.]{1,6}` however this will not allow `.` characters.

How can I make sure that only thing that regex expression does is checks length?

Example: http://regex101.com/r/eJ6pK5#pcre

Comment: Use only a dot? (i.e. `.{1,6}`) Also, your link isn't what you have in your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
[\s\S]{1,6}
```

The above will work with multiline.

Otherwise `.` represents any character other than new line.

So, `.{1,6}` will also do the trick.